# Why are isoprobabilty contours circles for uncorrelated functions and ellipse for correlated functions? Kindly explain.

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation-functions

I would like to know how to understand these and to learn how to go from a scatter plot to the isoprobabity contour plots. Thanks is advance!

Comment: Presumably regarding the location of the LIGO source black holes?

Comment: Two arbitrary but uncorrelated probability distributions will *not* necessarily generate circular isoprobability contours (normal dists will though) so you should reframe the question. Regarding scatter plots: you should fit a smooth surface (e.g. using a radial basis function) to the points and then construct the contours from that. This question may be better suited to [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Dear @lemon, thanks lot. I did mean correlation between two gaussian fields. I was able to think of the following answer. Please let me know if it is right. The probability that these two fields are correlated is given by $\frac{\exp{(-f^{*}M^{-1}f})}{(2\pi(det M)^{1/2}}$ where M is the correlation matrix . M is a diagonal matrix if they are uncorrelated and cross terms exist if they are correlated. Thus the contours give circles and ellipses respectively. Is the approach right?

Comment: @Ahalya That's correct. More generally, if the correlation can be written as some function of $Ax^2+By^2$, which the product of uncorrelated Gaussians can, then you will get circular contours (after scaling).